# How write all parameters jenkins in JSON file

Tags: json, jenkins-pipeline

I want to write all parameters of jenkins job pipeline build with parameters into a JSON file using `${params}`!
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace

writeJSON Jenkins step can take a list or map.

So i'd do

`writeJSON file: 'params.json', json: params, pretty: 4`

All jenkins parameters boil down to like a StringParameter or a BooleanParameter, even choices (which are just a string with a delimiter).

So to ensure you have a list you would need to craft it.
the Jenkins params map is immutable, so I suggest you build your own.

```
Map params = [
    'choiceParam': 'a\nb\nc',
    'stringParam': 'value1',
]

Map jsonParams = [:]
jsonParams.stringParam = params.stringParam
jsonParams.choiceParam = (params.choiceParam).split('\n')
print jsonParams​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You will need to use some loops if its not static known list to dynamically loop through all entries in the map.

Comment: That's work thank you,i have this output in JSON file
 `{
    "apis": "dev,qa,prod",
    "name": "CC",
    "version": "g3",
    "status": true
}` 
so there is a problem in value apis, i want to be like that `"apis":["dev","qa","prod"]` you have any idea ?

Comment: Sure. So params.apis is a string concatenated with new line characters. Essentially the current datatype does not match what you need. Your going to need to create a new map and have that value instead be a list. I would use split() or tokenize()